# Why anyone give negative vote on answer even though that answer is one of possibility of bug

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Any one asked question there is so many possibility of answer because as Answerer don't know all situation and also don't know expertise of coding of Questioner.

Many people on site giving **Down-votes** vote to the possibility answer. That the thing will discourage to new member. Is there anything which will prevent negative vote on possible answer?

Comment: Do you have examples of answers with many downvotes that you find useful? In my experience, this site is *very* generous regarding downvotes, if you compare it with other network sites.

Comment: @fabian yes you right the site is so good. but as an answerer if we are here for any one help and learning new things. But when we giving solution to anyone and they will give downvote that is not good thing even they have not mentioned any specification or criteria. Have look at one of my experience someone give downvote even question have no specificaion http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104707/how-to-add-js-before-body-end-tag/104708#104708

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anything which will prevent negative vote on possible answer?

No.
Every user has the right to up/down vote or ignore an answer.
However, serial up/downvoting is reversed the next day.

Comment: What do you think due to downvote answerer get demotivate to get further answer?

Comment: I don't know how everyone's mind works. Some people might get demotivated, some might get motivated to come up with better answer, some might not care at all.

Answer (score 1):

Question: Is there anything which will prevent negative vote on possible answer?

Answer: **No**

**Here are my suggestions:**

1. First check question description is clear
2. Use comment's to clarify even question better
3. Don't tried to answer quickly unless you are 100% sure

At the end answer the question and let the community decide what they think about your answer. If they like that they will upvote and don't like you will get downvote.

> *In positive side you loss **2 rep** and downvoter also loss **1 rep** too*

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I want to suggest community to set privileges for downvote as well because if any newbie have no clear knowledge  about magento and they will give anyone downvote that is unfair to answerer.

Comment: @PrashantValanda there is already limit for that **125 rep**  to get this privilege.